# Keep text in text field after submitting

Tags: php, html

I am having a issue keeping text in the text field that was previously there after pushing submit. I am using this:

```
 <input name="date" type="text" id="date" <?php if(isset($_POST['date'])){echo 'value="'.$_POST['date'].'"';} ?>/>
```

I also have this on successful submit so that it reloads the table but also removes whats above because it's refreshing.

```
echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"6\">";
```

My entire code=

```
 <?php

                     //  if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
                     if (isset($_POST['submit2']))

{
$con = mysql_connect("xx","xx_xx","xx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("xx_xx", $con);


$date = $_POST['date'];

$_SESSION['date'] = $_POST;

//Writes the to the server 

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `reservation__date` (`reservation_id`, `reservation_date`) 
VALUES
 ('000', '$date')") or die(mysql_error()); 
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{

$_SESSION['DATE'] = $_REQUEST['date'];
echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"6\">";  
mysql_close($con);
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the PRG principle (POST-redirect-GET), you need to track the POST data in the session.

I assume your do something like this after submit:

```
if (POST is fine) {

  do something;
  redirect;

} else {

  re-render page and show feedback

}
```

Since the server will discard any POST data on redirect, you need to track the POST data on every submit and re-populate the POST data on page load (GET).

```
$_SESSION['user_POST'] = $_POST;

if (POST is fine) ...
```

On your page that contains the form to submit:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_POST']) {
  $_POST = $_SESSION['user_POST'];
}
```

Ignore syntax, I'm not into PHP that much.

Comment: Never heard of it, mind explaining how I could do that, if you have tiem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your requirement

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['date'])){

$_SESSION['date'] = $_REQUEST['date'];
echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"6\">";
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['date'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are using meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" after submit the page. The page will refresh so if you want to get the text field after submitting you can use $_SESSION or $_COOKIES

Comment: I have edited my code please copy complete code and check it in your local system. Let me know working or not.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FOR TESTING

```
<?php  echo $_POST['date']; ?>
```

try setting to is equal to true if the above is right

```
<input name="date" type="text" id="date" <?php if(isset($_POST['date']) === true){echo 'value="'.$_POST['date'].'"';} ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are using session variable.. use `session_start();` at top of you page..
2. check if you have **method="POST"** in the form because by-default its GET..
3. check weather you have correct action field for the form such as `<form action="abc.php">`
4. if you want to put text in value, better check the condition within the value attribute and echo the value. because even if you don't write value in HTML insert tag.. It take as `value=""` . which creates an ambiguous condition later.

so better do

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post" >

<input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date'])){echo $_POST['date'];} ?>" />
 .......................
</form
```

**and now on abc.php**

```
<?php

 session_start(); // as you are using session variables..

 if (isset($_POST['submit2']))

{
$con = mysql_connect("xx","xx_xx","xx");
 if (!$con)
 {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("xx_xx", $con);


$date = $_POST['date'];

$_SESSION['date'] = $_POST['date']; // POST is an array carrying many elements so be specific which element you want. inthis case it is $_POST['date'];

//Writes the to the server 

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `reservation__date` (`reservation_id`, `reservation_date`) VALUES ('000', '$date')") or die(mysql_error()); 
$query = mysql_query($sql);

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{

 $_SESSION['DATE'] = $_REQUEST['date'];

 echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";

 echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"6\">";  

 mysql_close($con);
}
}

?>
```

hope this will help you...